# Java - is an array of type Class<? extends MyType> possible?

Tags: java, generics

I've just been diving into Java generics and have come across something puzzling. I have a List of Class objects. These Class objects are of classes that extend the class MyType. What I want to do is the following:

```
Class<? extends MyType>[] myArray = myList.toArray( Class<? extends MyType>[] );
```

Now I know this won't work. But how is it possible to create such an array? My trouble is that I need to pass this List as a Class array to a method. I'd rather avoid @SuppressWarnings and figure out if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is rule "don't mess arrays with generics". There is the restriction in Java that states that [creation of arrays of parameterized types is not allowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays). So, the answer for your question is **no**, you can't create an array of any generic types.

**UPD**: Consider using any collection type instead of arrays. They will work just fine.
 Or you can (but better not do that though) use array of non-generic elements and then cast them to appropriate type, suppressing warnings.

Comment: I cannot change the API I am using. The method in question takes as parameter Class<?>..., and what I have is a collection of Class<? extends MyType>.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the list as such but not instantiate as such. Must be instanced with concrete class substitutiona but then be assigned to whatever the captures.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the concrete type here which you also should know because of the type of myList.